# Payments - IAP or Third Party

Tags: ios, paypal, in-app-purchase

We are working on an iOS application that provides some credits (paid) that can be used within the app. We have few queries regarding this -

1. Can we go with third party payment gateways like paypal or similar or we need to implement IAP for this?
2. If we need to implement IAP then what will the sharing ratio?
3. If we use third party payment gateways and not IAP for this so is there any chance that Apple reject the app?

We have gone through the apple guideline for Payments, but didn't found that for all virtual purchasing devs must use the IAP. Also we didn't found any specific details on payment for virtual services that we can't use the third party payment services.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please go through apple review guidelines and your doubts will be cleared.

You can use third party payment gateway,if you are offering physical goods,service outside app. If you are selling your content or service inside app then you must use inapp-purchase.

As per [purchasing currencies guideline](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#purchasing-currencies),

1. Apps utilizing a system other than the In-App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an App will be rejected.
2. Apps that use IAP to purchase credits or other currencies must consume those credits within the App

Regrding your questions, answers are as below

1. You can't use third party payment gateway to provide credits which are using in app.
2. You may view [price matrix](http://forecomm.mptw.fr/templates/PriceMatrix.html) here.
3. Yes there is most probably chance of rejection if you implement third party payment gateway instead of IAP to provide credits into application.

You may read [Apple review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, one more question that, is there any extra commission in In-App purchase like paypal have on every transacation?

Comment: @iphonedev23 : No mate, You may have extra deduction in form of taxes from apple. :p

Comment: Ok and can i revert the payment in case of extra charged or if user want to redeem the point?

Comment: @iphonedev23 I dont know about it.

Comment: One more clarity on a point - 

1. If a user made some purchases on web to earn some points. These points will be used within the app. So can that user access those points in the app?
Note that user has made payment on the web  version of the same app and now using those points in the app. Hope apple will not reject the app in this case.

Comment: Correct.. Apple is not going to check how your website is functioning.. So They should not reject app..

Comment: This is the new link: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#in-app-purchase